# Java SVM training with images

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, svm

I have seen questions related to this post but it is little bit confusing.

I have gone through [kaggle site](http://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data)

Here we need to distingush between Dog and cat (Looking into training only).

I want to apply my svm java implementation in these "train" data.

1. How to do that. My Normal svm takes only numeric values with 1/-1 classification. 
   Here it is images.
   So i need to first convert the images into numerical data?
2. How will be the flow : convert to numeric data then do svm then what will be final result
3. Where can i find a large file (1GB) for training svm.Only numeric value not images.

I dont want to use libraries for that like libsvm. I need to do only training.

Any suggestion.

Comment: You need to read more on how SVM works. Your first intuition is correct, you need to convert them into numerical data. The simplest one, you can use color histogram. More sophisticated ones would be to extract features from the images, say, edges, shapes, etc. Then you feed those numerical features into SVM, together with the classification, in order to do your training.

Comment: i have done svm implementation in java and i am able to train numeric data. Spam not spam .Is there numerous way to convert images to features. But i need to do all conversions programatically. Is that possible

Comment: That's great. Have you read the image into your program? An image is basically a sequence of bytes. To get the color histogram, you can see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: :) justhalf i didnt tried with images.ok i will go through that link

Comment: 1 more doubt where can i get a 1GB dataset for training? not images ,features.

Comment: Use HSV format not RGB model to convert image to numerical values. First convert RGB to HSV model. HSV separate the important feature of image hence it is good for recognition

Comment: Is there any sample code to work out